# How to cancel a BlockBlobClient upload mid flow in c# in Blazor?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-blob-storage, blazor-webassembly

I am using Blazor Webassembly to upload files to a userupload area in Azure blob storage.

The code works fine, but I want to be able to offer the user the option to cancel (e.g. in a large upload of potentially a few files). Here's the code:

```
        public async Task<InfoBool> HandleFilesUpload(FileChangedEventArgs e, IProgress<Tuple<int, int, string>> progressHandler,
        IProgress<Tuple<int,string>> fileCountHandler, ExternalFileDTO fileTemplate, InfoBool isCancelling)
    {

        int FileCount =0;
        fileTemplate.CreatedBy = _userservice.CurrentUser;
        Tuple<int, string> reportfile;
        Tuple<int, int, string> CountProgressName;
        foreach (var file in e.Files)
        {
            FileCount++;
            reportfile = Tuple.Create(FileCount, file.Name);

            fileCountHandler.Report(reportfile);
            try
            {
                if (file == null)
                {
                    return new InfoBool(false, "File is null");

                }
                long filesize = file.Size;
                if (filesize > maxFileSize)
                {
                    return new InfoBool(false, "File exceeds Max Size");

                }
                fileTemplate.OriginalFileName = file.Name;

                var sendfile = await _azureservice.GetAzureUploadURLFile(fileTemplate);
                if (!sendfile.Status.Success) // There was an error so return the details
                {
                    return sendfile.Status;
                }
                CurrentFiles.Add(sendfile); // Add the returned sendfile object to the list
                BlockBlobClient blockBlobclient = new BlockBlobClient(sendfile.CloudURI);

                byte[] buffer = new byte[BufferSize];
                using (var bufferedStream = new BufferedStream(file.OpenReadStream(maxFileSize), BufferSize))
                {
                    int readCount = 0;
                    int bytesRead;
                    long TotalBytesSent = 0;
                    // track the current block number as the code iterates through the file
                    int blockNumber = 0;

                    // Create list to track blockIds, it will be needed after the loop
                    List<string> blockList = new List<string>();

                    while ((bytesRead = await bufferedStream.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, BufferSize)) > 0)
                    {
                        blockNumber++;
                        // set block ID as a string and convert it to Base64 which is the required format
                        string blockId = $"{blockNumber:0000000}";
                        string base64BlockId = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(blockId));

                        Console.WriteLine($"Read:{readCount++} {bytesRead / (double)BufferSize} MB");

                        // Do work on the block of data
                        await blockBlobclient.StageBlockAsync(base64BlockId, new MemoryStream(buffer, 0, bytesRead));
                        // add the current blockId into our list
                        blockList.Add(base64BlockId);
                        TotalBytesSent += bytesRead;
                        int PercentageSent = (int)(TotalBytesSent * 100 / filesize);
                        CountProgressName = Tuple.Create(FileCount, PercentageSent, file.Name);
                        if (isCancelling.Success) //Used an InfoBool so its passed by reference
                        {
                            break; // The user has cancelled, so wind up.
                        }
                        progressHandler.Report(CountProgressName);
                    }
                    // add the blockList to the Azure which allows the resource to stick together the chunks
                    if (isCancelling.Success)
                    {
                        await blockBlobclient.DeleteIfExistsAsync(); // Delete the blob created
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        await blockBlobclient.CommitBlockListAsync(blockList);
                    }
                    // make sure to dispose the stream once your are done
                    bufferedStream.Dispose();   // Belt and braces
                }
                //
                // Now make a server API call to verify the file upload was successful
                //
                // Set the file status to the cancelling, cos the server can delete the file.
                sendfile.Status = isCancelling;
                await _azureservice.VerifyFileAsync(sendfile);

                if (isCancelling.Success)
                {
                    break;      // This breaks out of the foreach loop
                }

            }
            catch (Exception exc)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(exc.Message);
            }
            finally
            {

            }
        }
        return new InfoBool(true, "All Ok");
```

The server creates a DB record for the upload and returns a SAS Key in the 'GetAzureUploadURLFile' which is then used to upload a blockblob and commit. Once done, the server is called again to tell it that the client has finished the upload. This allows the server to check it exists and verify the the content.

I have managed to provide an 'isCancelling' link to the UI thread by way of a general purpose class I use called InfoBool that will pass by reference.

After each block the progress handlers are called, and the 'InfoBool' is polled. So far so good.
If isCancelling, the innerloop breaks and then I need to tidy up.

The code as it is currently shows trying to just delete the blockBlobClient instead of commiting it.
That fails with an exception, I thought maybe its because it hadn't been comitted, and tried comitting the blockblobClient before deleting it, but the same result.

I have looked at the docs and it refers to abort mechanisms, but I can't see any examples of how to set up and use them. Anybody know how to abort the blockblobclient upload I have constructed?
Many thanks.

Comment: Have you tried using a CancellationToken?

Comment: Can you point me at an example of how to set one up and activate it?

Comment: The blobclient upload does offer a cancellation token, however I cant see that with the stagedblock calls for blockblob. I wonder if I am overthinking it on the basis the data is stages till comitted, but I can't see in the docs what happens if I don't commit the staged blocks? What is the timeout? Is there an exception etc?

Comment: Hi @PanagiotisKanavos, Thanks for the suggestion. After a lot of reading around, and figuring out how to use the cancellation token, I have modified the code to use one. 
I am still a bit confused however, how the OperationCancelledException gets fired without throwing it in my loop. However it does, and it works. Thanks again.
If I get a chance later I'll put the modified code out there to avoid others falling into the same traps. Cheers